# How do I connect to Websockets program running on my server?

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, websocket, server, pm2

I have a Websocket program running on Ubuntu machine on Digital Ocean. The code is shortened below.

```js
// server.ts
import ws from "ws";

const wss = new ws.Server({
  port: 3002,
});

const handler = applyWSSHandler({ wss, router: appRouter, createContext });
console.log("WebSocket Server listening on ws://localhost:3002");
...
```

I host the server using `nodemon server.ts` or `pm2 start server.ts`. The program compiles and  logs that Websocket Server is listening.

Now, here is a minimum code for a client which just checks if Websockets is active.

```js
// client.js
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3002'); // where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the IPv4 of my Ubuntu machine

ws.onopen = function (event) {
    console.log('connected');
};
```

Nothing gets logged, showing that the Websocket server isn't active.

I expect "connected" to be printed.

If I host my server locally instead of on Digital Ocean, and connect to "localhost:3002", "connected" does get printed out.

Is there something wrong with the way I am hosting the server, or am I connecting to the server wrongly?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can try expose your port, docs: https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/app-deploy-websockets/#externally-expose-your-service-and-check-that-the-port-is-correct

Comment: Do you need to us `wss://` when connecting to secure server rather than `ws://` for local server? Also, perhaps try [ws.onerror event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/error_event)  to get more information.

Comment: @Gary Thanks for the suggestion, I tried both wss:// and ws://, but both don't work. onerror event doesn't seem to print anything either.

Comment: Yes, I think I needed to expose the port. I did it by following these two tutorials. Thanks!

https://www.coderrocketfuel.com/article/how-to-deploy-a-next-js-website-to-a-digital-ocean-server#install-node-js

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6ci2iCckWc